# out of sync video output from adobe media encoder

Tags: video, audio, sync, encoding, adobe-media-encoder

What do I do? The video is ahead of the audio after encoding it using adobe media encoder.
I used the default settings and the video is also monster size(11Gb)
The original video is not out of sync, so how do I fix it?
And I want to convert it to .mp4 from .avi.
My converter, total video converter allows me to change the sampling rate, bit rate of audio and video. And frame rate for video.
Can I change it from here so that the video and audio will be in sync